# How to change HTML page after a PHP script receives a CURL request?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, curl

I'm implementing a sort of login system with specific requirements. The HTML form POSTs to a PHP script via AJAX. This script then sends data to another PHP script for processing via CURL.

Some time later, once processing is done, a PHP script needs to send a CURL request back to the original PHP script (or a new script) and make the HTML change to indicate whether or not login was successful.

How can I make the PHP script update the HTML page once it receives the CURL request?

Comment: How long is `Some time later`? and are you using a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically it would be impossible to update the DOM of a page **exactly** when one PHP page sends a request to another PHP page through CURL. This is because PHP is a server-side language; once the page has been loaded, PHP **cannot** update it.

In order to update the DOM **after** page load, you would need AJAX. You can achieve **almost** the same result through AJAX; simply poll the second PHP page every so often in AJAX. In your poll, check the content of the PHP page. If it matches the data sent from the first page, return the result, and use that to update the page.

Having said that, logins are typically handled with redirections and `$_SESSION` data. You should be submitting your login form to a validation service, and then authenticating the user. Once the user is authenticated, they should be redirected to a new page. You wouldn't typically need to use AJAX at all for this; I'd only recommend it if you are using Cordova or something similar.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have your PHP update the HTML, because PHP doesn't run in a browser.

You'll need to send the new HTML back to the front end, as a response to the AJAX, and use a Javascript callback to update the page.